# Including Dynamic Jquery Listview Elements in .serialize() Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a fairly simple jquery mobile form. I am using a submit handler to execute an ajax .serialize() method.

My js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: { ...
          ,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                type: form.method,
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "userInfo.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Data Save: " + data);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

to store the array in a mysql database using the following php.

```
$work_date = $_POST["work_date"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$add_members = $_POST["add_members"];
…

$sql = "INSERT INTO user ". "(work_date,name,add_members,jobnumber,st_time,end_time,st_mileage,end_mileage,work_type,instrument,per_diem,atv_no,comments,date) ". "VALUES('$work_date','$name','$add_members','$jobnumber','$st_time','$end_time',st_mileage=" . (!$st_mileage ? 'NULL' : (int)$st_mileage) . ",end_mileage=" . (!$end_mileage ? 'NULL' : (int)$end_mileage) . ",'$work_type','$instrument','$per_diem','$atv_no','$comments',NOW())";
```

The $_POST[] variables of course correspond to the name attribute for each element in the form.  This works really well for all except the ‘additional’ field in the image below.

[image]

This field is a dynamic jquery listview (an optional field) where the li element is only present when added to the form. This prevents me from being able to assign the name attribute to the li element/s before the form is serialized. Can someone pls enlighten me on properly including these elements in the serialized array and thusly storing to the db?

Comment: You can't "serialize" lists...try to convert them to "option select" with "multiple selects" and then you will be able to use serialize, or change serialize to other way to get the data.

Comment: You can use either the method @Asfo mentioned or you can use `hidden` input element in each `<li>` element which stores the correspondent value in it, or before calling your ajax, you can iterate through your list and read the `<li>` values and add them your your form and then use serialize.

Comment: I would ideally like to keep the jquery listview element if at all possible(user experience). Can you provide a short example @EhsanT? I have been making attempts at adding name="add_members" upon click of the add button.  This however is not working for me. Thoughts? $('#addPersonel').click(function() {
 var addMember = $('#member').val();

 if(addMember != '') {
  $('#contributionList').append('<li><a>' + addMember + '</a><a class="deleteMe" id="members" name="add_members"></a></li>').listview('refresh');

Comment: Is this your actual code that you have right now?

Comment: yes? But just added.

Comment: OK, first of all, the `id` should be unique. so you should not have `id="members"`. if you really need to have an id, then it'e better to have at least a JavaScript counter and add it at then end of the id like this: `id="members'+iCnt+'"`(which `iCnt` is a variable that you +/- it manually on adding and removing each member)

Comment: And then, you can add a hidden `<input>` in the same section, which contains the name in it like this: `$('#contributionList').append('<li><a>' + addMember + '</a><a class="deleteMe" id="members" name="add_members"></a><input type="hidden" name="hdnMemberName[]" value="'+addMember+'"></li>').listview('refresh');` Please notice the `hdnMemberName[]`. it will create an `array` when you will get it in the `php` side

Comment: How should I set up the php variable for this. Current: $add_members = $_POST["add_members"];  New: $add_members = $_POST[hdnMemberName[]]; ??

Comment: No, since it is being posted as an array, then in your `php` you can have something like this: `$add_members = $_POST['hdnMemberName']; for($iCnt = 0, $cnt = count($add_members); $iCnt < $cnt; $iCnt++){ $add_member = $add_members[$iCnt]; }` and then do what ever you want to do with them in your `for loop`

Comment: Or if you just need a comma separated string you can simply use `$add_members = implode(",", $_POST['hdnMemberName']);`